# How to download CSV file after creating using json2csv

Tags: node.js, csv, download

I am generating a CSV file in which my data is writing very well using `json2csv` node module.
This is my code to create a csv file with my data.

```
 Lead.find({ownerId:owner._id}, function(err, data){
                if(err){res.json(err)}
                  else{
                    res.json(data);  
                      var fields = ['lead', 'salutation', 'fname','lname','title','email','mobile','rating','address','city','state','zcode','company','industry','empSize','lsource'];
                      var csv = json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields });
                      var path='./public/csv/file'+Date.now()+'.csv'; 
                       fs.writeFile(path, csv, function(err,data) {
                        if (err) {throw err;}
                        else{ 
                          console.log('file Created');
                         //I need to download above creating csv file here
                        }
                    }); 
                  }

              });
```

So, Now I want to know how can I download created CSV file after generate csv.
I tried `res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.status(200).send(data);`

But its not working ...

Please let me know how can I do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all this..... I got a solution.
At the backend in Node.js API `res.download(path)` is working fine.
At the front side I am using Angular.js. So, to make it workable I need to  create an anchor tag and trigger a click event like this

`var anchor=angular.element('<a/>');
  anchor.attr({href:'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,'  + encodeURI($scope.dattaa),target:'_blank',download:'lead'+Date.now()+'.csv'})[0].click();`

Now its working fine.

Thanks guys for help.

Comment: You should have checked postman or hit from browser as this question is not valid

Answer (score 3):

If you are using express 4.x you can simply use [res.download()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download)

```
 Lead.find({ownerId:owner._id}, function(err, data){
            if(err){res.json(err)}
              else{
                  var fields = ['lead', 'salutation', 'fname','lname','title','email','mobile','rating','address','city','state','zcode','company','industry','empSize','lsource'];
                  var csv = json2csv({ data: data, fields: fields });
                  var path='./public/csv/file'+Date.now()+'.csv'; 
                   fs.writeFile(path, csv, function(err,data) {
                    if (err) {throw err;}
                    else{ 
                      res.download(path); // This is what you need
                    }
                }); 
              }

          });
```

Comment: I think, is there any middleware conflicting in app.js, It is possible??????????????????????

Answer (score 1):

```
json2csv({ data: myCars, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        var path='./csv'+Date.now()+'.csv'; 
        fs.writeFile(path, csv, function(err,data) {
         if (err) {throw err;}
         else{ 
           console.log('file Created');
           res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
           res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
           res.status(200).send(csv);
          //I need to download above creating csv file here
         }
     }); 
    }
});
```

Replace your code with this.

Comment: its not working even `res.donwload(path)` is also not working..... and there is no any console error is showing

Comment: I think, is there any middleware conflicting in app.js, It is possible??????????????????????